# How to get hardkey events in a system overlay with a unfocusable view?

Tags: java, android, view, overlays

As I described in the Title, my problem is that there is a view that is not focusable. So now I've no idea how to get KeyEvents from the View...

**Edit:**
If possible, event can be listened from service

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code in a fragment to close a full screen pager view and it works

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_addetails, container1,
            false);
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                    && pager.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

or this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
           //do code
            return true
}
        return false;
}
```

maybe this will help
if not please describe the full scenario for what your are trying to achieve

Comment: I've tried that before like overriding onKey function or set onkeylistener but I think it does not work because the view isn't focusable. Ok now I tell you the full scenario: I've got a service. From there I'm showing an overlay with a view in it. And from there your code doesn't work. It just gets ignored...

Comment: see the edited code

this is working for me set the view you are inflating  to be   setFocusableInTouchMode(true); and it should work
good luck

Comment: Nonono it' s a systemoverlay and it should NOT be focusable, the focus should go under the view!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out, that I can use the MediaButton to get the KeyEvent I wanted. I just needed to declare a BroadcastReceiver and register it. Thats it!